# Make only one column appear at the start of Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

[According to latest documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-builder.html), one can set the maximum number of grid columns form authors can create:

```
<property
    as="xs:integer"
    name="oxf.fb.grid.max-columns"
    value="4"/>
```

Because of some constraints in our use of Orbeon, I set the maximum of columns to "1". However, when I open the Form Builder to create a new form, the default arrangement shows a grid of two columns and one row, one cell containing a text field.

Now, if I delete the second column, I can't add a new column again, in line with the property set. But the fact that you can leave the two columns annoys me.

Is there a way to make default controls use only one column when opening the Form Builder?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change this right now. Orbeon Forms 2017.2 will, in addition, have a [12-column layout](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2738), which means that `oxf.fb.grid.max-columns` will have no effect. I think that constraining a form to follow an n-column layout would be a new feature of the product.